# How do i avoid nested for loop in R which takes more processing time

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataset where i need to tokenize the words and find the frequency of each word, i can achieve this by doing for loop in R.

```
InputData <- To_Find_Categories
ShtDesc_Token_all <- ""
ShtDesc_Token <- ""
for(i_ID in 1:nrow(InputData))
  #for(i_ID in 1:20)  
{
  ShtDesc_Token <- regmatches(InputData$short_description, gregexpr("((?![0-9]+)[A-Za-z0-9]+)",
                                                                    InputData$short_description, perl = TRUE))[[i_ID]]
  ShtDesc_Token_all <- append(ShtDesc_Token_all, ShtDesc_Token)
}

X<- sort(table(unlist(ShtDesc_Token_all)))

write.csv(X, "temp.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

#

But it takes much processing time, i want to avoid the for loop, how i can do this?
Data is like in .csv format, i can give sample records

```
data.table::fread("number,parent , short_description
GECTASK0011264,  GECHG0036340 ,   Restore Request
GECTASK0011265,  GECHG0036340 ,   Restore Request
GECTASK0011748,  GECHG0038670,    lkj
GECTASK0011797 , GECHG0034985 ,   vm down-grade
GECTASK0011798,  GECHG0034985 ,   vm down-grade
GECTASK0012252 , GECHG0040437  ,  remove server from load
GECTASK0012253 , GECHG0040437 ,   remove server from load
GECTASK0012328 , GECHG0034983 ,   vm down-grade
GECTASK0012329 , GECHG0034983 ,   vm down-grade")
```

Comment: Why does your title mention nested loops? What do you mean by "too much time"?

Comment: why for loop? `sort(table(unlist(strsplit(InputData$short_description,"\\W"))))` is enough

Comment: for loop is takes much time , i have only given couple of records ,there were millions of such records in a .csv file.Thats why it takes much time.Sorry it is my mistake the title should be only for loop not nested..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try this

You do not need for loop in this case.

```r
input <-    data.table::fread("number,parent , short_description
    GECTASK0011264,  GECHG0036340 ,   Restore Request
    GECTASK0011265,  GECHG0036340 ,   Restore Request
    GECTASK0011748,  GECHG0038670,    lkj
    GECTASK0011797 , GECHG0034985 ,   vm down-grade
    GECTASK0011798,  GECHG0034985 ,   vm down-grade
    GECTASK0012252 , GECHG0040437  ,  remove server from load
    GECTASK0012253 , GECHG0040437 ,   remove server from load
    GECTASK0012328 , GECHG0034983 ,   vm down-grade
    GECTASK0012329 , GECHG0034983 ,   vm down-grade")

tmp <- paste(input$short_description,collapse = " ")

tmp.splt <- stringr::str_split(tmp, pattern= " ")[[1]]

table(tmp.splt)
#> tmp.splt
#> down-grade       from        lkj       load     remove    Request 
#>          4          2          1          2          2          2 
#>    Restore     server         vm 
#>          2          2          4
```

Created on 2018-08-10 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

### Or

Use this one-liner (From @Onyambu 's comment):

```r
sort(table(unlist(strsplit(InputData$short_description,"\\W"))))
```

Comment: You do not actually need to collapse just `sort(table(unlist(strsplit(InputData$short_description,"\\W"))))` is enough

Comment: @Onyambu Thanks, that one-liner looks much cooler than mine! I added to the answer, hope you don't mind.